# how to call getNamedItem() and nodeValue() of DOMDocument within function

Tags: domdocument, nodevalue

I have an XML to import using DOMDocument. To avoid lot of foreach loop used to retreive nodeValue (), I used it as separate function. It is not working for me in live server. The function is as follows:

```
        <?php
    function Single_ParseDomObjXML($parameter){
          $value='';
          foreach($parameter as $get_val)
            {
                $value=$get_val->nodeValue;
            }
            return $value;
      }

    $text_tags=$events->getElementsByTagName('text');
                    foreach($text_tags as $text_inf){
                        $event['text']['promo']=Single_ParseDomObjXML($text_inf->getElementsByTagName('promo'));
                        $event['text']['spec']=Single_ParseDomObjXML($text_inf->getElementsByTagName('spec'));
                        $event['event_desc']=nl2br(Single_ParseDomObjXML($text_inf->getElementsByTagName('desc')));
                    }
?>
```

Comment: What do you expect to get when you run this and what do you actually get?

Comment: Hi Steve,
I get error message as  "Fatal error:  Can't use function return value in write context in /home/mymusicdates/public_html/controls.php"

Comment: this error got fixed. I was using PHP VERSION 4. hence the issue arised. Once after upgrading to new version got fixed thanks steve.